# <![CDATA[]> in XML tags

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, cdata

I have an XML file that is parsed with a PHP file.  I have to include a lot of "Special" characters which need CDATA in order to parse correctly.

Is there a way to tell my PHP file to read all the tags as if there was a  block at the begging and and of the tag?

As of right now for every XML tag a create i have to put a CDATA block:

```
<tag><![CDATA[blah.......]]></tag>
```

Is there a way to set it up where I don't have to write CDATA every time for evey tag in my XML?

Comment: If you control the creation of the XML, then you can certainly escape the entities to avoid having to use CDATA. If you are using something like SimpleXML, you could always extend it and make it treat all data as if it were enclosed in CDATA without really being so, but that seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

CDATA is a bad idea! There's a number of problems with it. What you should do instead, is use `htmlspecialchars()` for every value.

Alright.. Hold your downvotes! Here are some issues with CDATA.

First, the easy one: You cannot escape the `]]>` sequence. This may not seem like a huge deal, but if you are picking any method for 'escaping character sequences', you really should pick one where every single sequence is escapable.

Now for the big one: CDATA is often used as a hack to inject Latin1 data into a UTF-8 document. People figure, I have an escaping problem in XML, so I will use CDATA as a workaround.

In CDATA *any* character sequence is allowed, and the specified character encoding of the XML document is no longer relevant in this block. However, any type of text actually does have a character encoding, and instead of convering the encoding (what you should do) you 'hack' around this by wrapping it in CDATA.

It is also not a viable way to encode binary data, as control-characters are still not allowed.

So, CDATA kind of implies 'here be dragons', there are bytes here that are not in a specified encoding, all I can tell you there are no control characters.

This is a bad idea for the consumer, because all assumptions about character encoding is now gone.

Here are some links:

- [CDATA in xml.. bad idea?](http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/184)
- [Wikipedia CDATA, Issues with encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Issues_with_encoding)
- Bonus: someone on the consumer side that ran into the issues: [problems reading CDATA section with special chars (ISO-8859-1 encoding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997236/problems-reading-cdata-section-with-special-chars-iso-8859-1-encoding)

Comment: This isn't really a helpful answer without *you* explaining why CDATA is bad. (Not my -1, BTW. Just speculating on *why* you got the -1).

Comment: "CDATA is a bad idea! There's a number of problems with it." Can you please expand on that a bit? Telling people to "Google around" leaves much to be desired in a Q&A site.

Comment: There is **no** problem with non-HTML-entitied characters in XML files if you know what you are doing. CDATA is *the* way to store stuff in XML. If you have evidence to the contrary, show it.

Comment: @Pekka: I honestly thought avoiding CDATA was common knowledge.. apparently not

Comment: CDATA does not mean you can use *any* character encoding. Anyone using them to dump invalid character data is producing invalid XML. But that's the fault of people being dumb. It's no reason not to use CDATA sections when used properly. The last paragraph in your wiki link makes sense though; however, note that many HTML entities are invalid in XML. Essentially what should be escaped is the HTML special characters `<` `>` `&` and quotes. I took the liberty of changing that in your answer (assuming that's what you meant)

Comment: You *can* escape the `]]>` btw, with `<![CDATA[]]]]><![CDATA[>]]>`

Comment: @Pekka: but is it not true that you can embed more data/additional bytes when not using CDATA. I agree that using CDATA is fine when you know what you're doing, but most of the time it's used as a nasty workaround for bad programming :)

Comment: Whoops and and I did indeed mean specialchars, not entities. Thnx for the edit :)

Comment: @Evert you're welcome. The point of CDATA is essentially that you can use `<` `>` etc. without having to encode them. That's basically all (and I agree it's a rare enough occurrence that you need that, which the Wiki article makes clear enough). Everything else (= the idea that you can output ISO-8859-1 data in a UTF-8 document) is just a misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us specifically what "special characters" you're referring to, but I'm assuming you mean some kind of accented characters, or characters in a non-latin alphabet, etc?

In most cases the problem can be solved by outputting the document using the UTF-8 character set.

In the remaining cases, it can be solved by using XML entities -- eg `&#160;`.

Both of these are better solutions than using CDATA.